# Oracle: Update based on cyclical select

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-update, subquery

I am having difficulty figuring out oracle query for  Following table, where i have to update based on  following criteria.

**Requirement:**

Here key is **account_number** based on account_number ,if the account have more than one user_numbers and out of those user_numbers if any user_number is not associated to any other account other than key, update that user_number stat to 'I',and leave user_number which has multiple accounts(can have key plus other accounts) as it is.If account have only one use do-not do anything.

```
create table cust_account(user_number number(10),account_number number(10),stat char(1));

Insert into cust_account(user_number,account_number,stat)values(123,345,'A')
Insert into cust_account(user_number,account_number,stat)values(226,345,'A')
Insert into cust_account(user_number,account_number,stat)values(226,456,'A')
Insert into cust_account(user_number,account_number,stat)values(556,767,'A')
```

commit;

Input:
[image]

**Expected Output;**
Here account_number 345 has two user_numbers and out of which 123 user has only one account so deactivated.
And 767 has only one use so don't even select it while updating.
[image]

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an `update` query, then I would recommend a correlated subquery:

```
update cust_account ca
set stat = 'I'
where stat = 'A' 
  and exists (select 1 
              from cust_account ca1 
              where ca1.stat = 'A'
                and ca1.account_number = ca.account_number 
                and ca1.user_number > ca.user_number)
```

If you want a `select`, then use `row_number()`:

```
select ca.*,
    case when stat = 'A' and row_number() over(partition by account_number, stat order by user_number desc) > 1
        then 'I'
        else stat
    end new_stat
from cust_account ca
```

Comment: here when I use my account number as 767 it is updating user_numbers which are not even related.
update cust_account ca
set stat = 'I'
where 
    stat = 'A' 
    and exists (select 1 from cust_account ca1 where ca1.account_number = 767 and ca1.stat = 'A' and ca1.user_number > ca.user_number).Expectation is it should be unchanged ,because this account have only one user_number

Comment: @JohnDoe: that's not how to use the query. If you want to filter, then do it in the outer query: `update cust_account ca
set stat = 'I'
where 
    stat = 'A'  and ca.account_number = 767
    and exists (
        select 1 
        from cust_account ca1 
        where 
            ca1.stat = 'A'
            and ca1.account_number = ca.account_number 
            and ca1.user_number > ca.user_number
    )`

Comment: Here key is account_number if i send 345 it should update 'I' only 123 because it has two users and one of which has more than one account, if i send 767 it should not update 556 user or any other users because it has only one user-account.

Comment: @JohnDoe: this works as intended. You can play around in this db fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b641bae842270a5b9a02e568248fd836

Comment: How can just write the query for select which returns user_number which has only one user out of those 2,and which takes account_number key

Comment: with ca as 
(select user_number from cust_account 
where stat = 'A' and account_number in (
select account_number from cust_account where account_number = 345
group by account_number having count(account_number) > 1
)) 
select * from cust_account where user_number not in
(select user_number from cust_account group by user_number having count(user_number) > 1) 
and user_number in (select user_number from ca); I wrote something like this how can i modify this?

Comment: @JohnDoe: comments are not meant to ask multiple questions like that. I provided a working answer to your *original* question, as you can see in the fiddle I provided. If you have more questions, then you should ask *a new question*, providing all necessary debugging details.

Comment: Thanks for the help